# jQuery select DIV by class name starting from top

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

I have a structure like the following to create a one page web application, using some scroll functionalities:

```
<div class="home_section"></div> <!-- 1 -->
<div class="home_section"></div> <!-- 2 -->
<div class="home_section"></div> <!-- 3 -->
<div class="home_section"></div> <!-- 4 -->
```

I need to scroll to each of the above DIVs when the scroll event starts.
So, for example, when the scroll starts, if the first DIV visible from top is `<!-- 2 -->`, the body will have to scroll to the DIV `<!-- 3 -->` automatically.

This is what I am doing:

```
if ($(this).attr('id') == 'home') {
    $(document).on("scrollstart", function (e) {
        console.log('scrolling started on home');

         e.preventDefault();

         var next = $(this).find(".home_section"); //here I need to calculate which is the next DIV to scroll to
         $('html, body').animate({
               scrollTop: next.offset().top
          });

    });
}
```

The problem is that I do not know how to check which is the first `.home_section` DIV visibile starting from top, so I am unable to calculate which is the next target DIV to scroll to.

Thanks for ay help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would loop through all the `.home_sections` divs, and get the first `:visible` like this

```
var divs = $(".home_section");
for(var x = 0; x < divs.length; x++){
    if($(divs[x]).is(":visible")){
        //do what you need here 
        var me = divs[x];
        var next = x < divs.length - 1 ? divs[x] : undefined;
        if(next){
            //do the scroll
        }
        //then break the for loop
        break;
    }
}
```

This way you have an array of divs, you find the first visible and then you have the reference to the `nth+1` div.

Another solution that should work:

```
var firstVisible = $(".home_section:visible:eq(0)");
var next = $(firstVisible).next();
```

hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

next div would be $(this).next();

```
var next = $(this).next();
```

But you would need to modify this line for it to work for all divs:

```
if ($(this).attr('id') == 'home')
```

Answer (score -1):

Modify the line `var next = $(this).find(".home_section");` as below to get first div with class "home_section".

**var next = $(this).getElementsByClassName("home_section")[0];**

Comment: This is at least a very strange jQuery answer, if not invalid completely. getElementsByClassName is a vanilla method, not jQuery.